# CPU utilization of python script when I used BPF filters

Tags: python, linux, networking, cpu-usage, bpf

I got code from [here](http://allanrbo.blogspot.in/2011/12/raw-sockets-with-bpf-in-python.html).

```
from binascii import hexlify
from ctypes import create_string_buffer, addressof
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, SOL_SOCKET
from struct import pack, unpack

sniff_interval=120
# A subset of Berkeley Packet Filter constants and macros, as defined in
# linux/filter.h.

# Instruction classes
BPF_LD = 0x00
BPF_JMP = 0x05
BPF_RET = 0x06

# ld/ldx fields
BPF_H = 0x08
BPF_B = 0x10
BPF_ABS = 0x20

# alu/jmp fields
BPF_JEQ = 0x10
BPF_K = 0x00

def bpf_jump(code, k, jt, jf):
    return pack('HBBI', code, jt, jf, k)

def bpf_stmt(code, k):
    return bpf_jump(code, k, 0, 0)


# Ordering of the filters is backwards of what would be intuitive for
# performance reasons: the check that is most likely to fail is first.
filters_list = [
    # Must have dst port 67. Load (BPF_LD) a half word value (BPF_H) in
    # ethernet frame at absolute byte offset 36 (BPF_ABS). If value is equal to
    # 67 then do not jump, else jump 5 statements.
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 36),
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 5201, 0, 5),

    # Must be UDP (check protocol field at byte offset 23)
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_B | BPF_ABS, 23),
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 0x06, 0, 3),

    # Must be IPv4 (check ethertype field at byte offset 12)
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 12),
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 0x0800, 0, 1),

    bpf_stmt(BPF_RET | BPF_K, 0x0fffffff), # pass
    bpf_stmt(BPF_RET | BPF_K, 0), # reject
]

# Create filters struct and fprog struct to be used by SO_ATTACH_FILTER, as
# defined in linux/filter.h.
filters = ''.join(filters_list)
b = create_string_buffer(filters)
mem_addr_of_filters = addressof(b)
fprog = pack('HL', len(filters_list), mem_addr_of_filters)

# As defined in asm/socket.h
SO_ATTACH_FILTER = 26

# Create listening socket with filters
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0x0800)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, fprog)
s.bind(('eth0', 0x0800))

while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(65565)
    #print "*****"
    print 'got data from', addr, ':', hexlify(data) #Have to print data, then only the CPU is 2%
```

I was testing with `iperf3`, generating traffic from another laptop to my laptop via  Ethernet cable. The server(My Laptop) listing on 5021 and client(Another Laptop) sending data.

- If I **comment** the line `print 'got data from', addr, ':',
  hexlify(data)`, and run the script, the CPU utilization of script
  goes to up 30%, 40% in presence of 100MB traffic.
- If I **uncomment** the line `print 'got data from', addr, ':',
  hexlify(data)` and ran again, the CPU is down to `2%` in presence of same amount of traffic. I checked in
  `htop`

So, what's happing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet that either `hexlify()`, or most likely `print` (as it has to synchronize with STDOUT) are giving your main thread a much needed break and a room to breathe instead of just pounding the socket read-out in the infinite `while` loop

Try adding `time.sleep(0.05)` (import `time` first, of course) instead of the print statement and check the CPU usage again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I don't want use `sleep`; high stream of data/traffic could get on the interface. What if we lose some traffic or something else?

Comment: You won't lose anything provided sufficient buffer on your socket, you'll just give other threads/processes some room to breathe - the very same thing probably happens when you call `print/hexlify()`, you just don't control it directly.